# PNG file in Java JAR

Tags: java, image, swing, png

I made a program that has lots of images in it. It was running successfully with no problems in my Netbeans IDE. But when I clean and build it. Some of its JFrame doesn't load because of the image's file extension. Here's the sample code:

```
label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("Images/test.PNG")));
```

Well, it does work but if I change the code to this:

```
label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("Images/test.png")));
```

You see, I changed the file extension to lowercase and it isn't working anymore.

Question: Why is this happening? And is there a possible solution where I don't need to change every single extension of the file in my code?

This only happens when I build a jar file, not when it's on my IDE.

Comment: Wild guess: you are building with Windows and using the jar on Linux?

Comment: Yes I am building with Windows, and I'm using it in Windows too.

Comment: When you call getResource without a leading / it will be relative to the calling class's package.  You might try opening the jar (it's just a zip file) and inspecting it, to make sure that "Images/test.png" exists inside the package of the class referred to by "getClass".  If it is in the root of the jar file, then just put a / at the front of your getResource parameter.

Comment: Open the JAR file and check what the file-name and path name actually is. Windows file names are case insensitive but when the files are added to a JAR they are accessed in a case sensitive manner.

Comment: @apokryfos if it is case sensitive, are you saying that I should change my code and copy the file names in a case sensitive manner? Would that be my best choice?

Comment: @Pete Let me put it this way. If your file is called `test.PNG` and you refer to it as `test.png` then you're referring to the wrong file. Just make sure you're referring to the file with the correct file-name.

Comment: @apokryfos Got it. Thank you very much

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Always refer to everything by correct case - saves you a lot of trouble in the long run. While windows file system is only case preserving, but not sensitive, even that becomes quickly ambigous when file names contain non-ascii characters. Not to mention Unix, which is traditionally case-sensitive.